# I want to embed custom emojis in my Open-Source Social Network projects

Tags: php, social-networking

I'm planning for a website that I'm going to be creating that runs on Open-Source Social Network and was wondering how to embed custom emoji that users will be able to use when making a post or a DM or if it was even possible to do so.

An example that I want is: user types :ballcap: and sends the post. The system then shows an svg of a ball cap in place of ":ballcap:".

Would I need to make a component that does that? Or do I use something like twemoji and edit the code? Or is there something else I should do?

Sorry if I sound stupid, I'm a beginner

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [emojionearea](https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea).

If you create an input, for example a textarea, as follows:

```
<textarea id="example"></textarea>
```

then you can use a little bit of JavaScript to link emojionearea to that input so the user can add an emoji from the emojionearea picker into that input.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example").emojioneArea();
  });
</script>
```

Also, to enable emojionearea to parse user input strings into emoji like :ballcap, you need to add the `shortnames` option.
As easy as that.